# Below a widget in XML

Tags: java, android, xml

i've tried to fix this problem but every way that i tried went wrong. i'm trying to add a BottomNavigationView below the FrameLayout but everytime the BottomNavigationView keep up of the FrameLayout or inside it. What could i do?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:background="#2b2b2b"
     android:id="@+id/coordinator"
     tools:context=".Home">

    <android.widget.FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        (...)
    </android.widget.FrameLayout>
    
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bottom_nav_frame"
        android:background="#2b2b2b"
        app:iconTint="#ffffff"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In your BottomNavigationView add this line

```
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```